# Call the function 24 hours after the first call in node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, cron, scheduled-tasks

How i can call the function 24 hours after the first call in node.js?

Or 24 hours after the execution of a specific request to this node.js server?

And execute it with the same parameters

*(function must sent email to user)*

Comment: this is a cron job?, mmm try to make a triger in your bd, or a thread?

Comment: @art201214 This does not seem to be a question, this seems to be a request for work. What have you tried so far? where is your code?

Answer (score 0):

I think this is a much bigger question that might be dependent on the type of architecture you have. The simple answer is to investigate some sort of [scheduler](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-schedule), or cron task, however the better solution might be to distribute these systems and setup some sort of messaging system live [Rabbit MQ](https://www.rabbitmq.com/).

When the first function runs, you can send a message via rabbit to the system that handles emails and run this much later, thereby reducing the load on the original system, or protecting it if it goes down.